# Powerset of $A\times B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

$A = \{0,1\}$ and $B = \{1,2\}$, find $P(A\times B).$

And I found $A\times B = \{(0,1),(0,2),(1,1),(1,2)\}$

So if I wanted $P(A\times B),\text{would I do this:} \\
P(A\times B) = \{\emptyset,\{(0,1)\},\{(0,2)\},\{(1,1)\},\{(1,2)\},\{(0,1),(0,2)\},\{(0,1),(1,1)\}...,\{(0,1),(0,2),(1,1),(1,2)\}\}$

Or am I doing this wrong? $A\times B$ has $4$ elements, so $P(A\times B)$ should have $2^{n}$ elements, right?

Comment: That's correct; you should get $16$ elements.

Answer (score 0):

Power sets of cartesian products are quite fun actually.

Power set of cartesian product of n sets is actually set of all n-ary relations of elements of given sets.

Such power sets can be used to construct set off all functions from one set into another(can you see how?)

In conclusion you are correct,and you are doing it right.